# Get correct result from mysql query

Tags: sql

I have the following tables:

```
**products** which has these fields: id,product,price,added_date
**products_to_categories** which has these fields: id,product_id,category_id
**adverts_to_categories** -> id,advert_id,category_id
**adverts** which has these fields: id,advert_name,added_date,location
```

I can not execute sql that will return to me all products that are from category 14 and that are owned by advert located in London. So I have 4 tables and 2 conditions - to be from category 14 and the owner of the product to be from London. I tried many variants to execute sql but none of the results were correct.. Do I need to use Join and which Join - left, right, full? How the correct sql will look like? thank you in advance for your help and sorry for boring you :)

This is what I have tried so far:

```
SELECT p.id, product, price, category_id, 
       p.added_date, adverts.location, adverts.id 
FROM products p, 
     products_to_categories ptc, 
     adverts, 
     adverts_to_categories ac 
WHERE ptc.category_id = "14" 
  AND ptc.product_id=p.id 
  AND ac.advert_id=adverts.id 
  AND adverts.location= "London"
```

Comment: What did you try and how were the results incorrect?

Comment: SELECT p.id, product, price, category_id, p.added_date, adverts.location, adverts.id
FROM products p, products_to_categories ptc, adverts, adverts_to_categories ac
WHERE ptc.category_id = "14"
AND ptc.product_id=p.id
AND ac.advert_id=adverts.id
AND adverts.location= "London"   but this returns wrong results..

Comment: First statrt by never using implicit syntax again. It is asql antipattern and very poor programming technique.

Comment: How are the results incorrect?

Comment: I'd say that right now you have an unintended cross join due to using implicit joins.

Answer (score 1):

pretty basic logic

```
Select * from Products P
INNER JOIN Products_To_Categories PTC ON P.ID = PTC.Product_ID
INNER JOIN Adverts_to_Categories ATC ON ATC.Category_Id = PTC.Category_ID
INNER JOIN Adverts AD on AD.ID = ATC.Advert_ID
WHERE PTC.Category_ID = 14 and AD.Location = 'LONDON'
```

you would only need a LEFT or right join IF you wanted records from a table which didn't exist in other tables.
so for example, if you wanted all products even if a records even those without a category, then you would use a LEFT Join instead of inner.

Comment: thank you guys, xQbert your sql works ! thank you all for your help !

Comment: You may want to refer to this link http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html.  It's one of my favorite sites explaining the different types of joins.

Answer (score 1):

The following statement should return all columns from the product table in category with id 14 and all adverts located in London:

```
select p.* from products p
inner join products_to_categories pc on p.id = pc.product_id
inner join adverts_to_categories ac on pc.category_id = ac.category_id
inner join adverts a on a.id = ac.advert_id
where pc.category_id = 14
and ac.location = 'London';
```

You should remember to add an index to the column location if you are doing these string-based queries very often.